# scons compile under windows

Tags: python, windows, scons

I am trying to compile a project from source. SConscript file is prepared for linux however author says it can be built under windows as well. I found severel bugs in file. However I am not good at python. So I can't figure out whats wrong with the file. Here is the error and lines that causes error.

Error:

```
KeyError: 'WITH_PYTHON':
  File "C:\Users\cihan\Desktop\clingo-4.5.4-source\SConstruct", line 140:
    SConscript('SConscript', variant_dir=join('build', GetOption('build_dir')), duplicate=0, exports=['env', 'opts'])
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.5.0\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 604:
    return method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.5.0\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 541:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.5.0\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 250:
    exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File "C:\Users\cihan\Desktop\clingo-4.5.4-source\SConscript", line 197:
    if env['WITH_PYTHON'] == "auto":
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.5.0\SCons\Environment.py", line 410:
    return self._dict[key]
```

Script:

```
with_python = False
if env['WITH_PYTHON'] == "auto":
    if conf.CheckPythonConfig() or \
       conf.CheckWithPkgConfig("python", ["python", "python2", "python-2.7", "python-2.6", "python-2.5", "python-2.4", "python3", "python-3.4", "python-3.3", "python-3.2", "python-3.1", "python-3.0"]):
        with_python = True
        DEFS["WITH_PYTHON"] = 1
elif env['WITH_PYTHON']:
    if not conf.CheckLibs("python", env['WITH_PYTHON'], "Python.h"):
        failure = True
    else:
        with_python = True
        DEFS["WITH_PYTHON"] = 1
```

Comment: You probably need to set the environment variable. I think on windows it's `set WITH_PYTHON=auto`

Comment: I added this line "env = Environment(tools = ['mingw'])" to make script find mingw toolset. May be I override some settings. Is there a way to append or replace 'tools' thing with mingw ?

Comment: I believe you should be able to update the environment. I suspect `env['tools'] = ['mingw']` should add that to your environment?

Comment: Why does your error message say that the "if ... == "auto": " key error happens in line 197, when on my machine with a freshly unpacked archive it's actually line 192? It would also be helpful when you tell us which command line parameters you use to try and build clingo. (It would also have been helpful to tell us that this is the software you're interested in, and in which version.) Finally, can you give a reference to where exactly the author claims that the build works fine under Windows too?

Comment: Please post a URL to the project you are trying to compile.  Also have you asked your question to that project's mailing list and/or IRC channel?  Porting from linux to windows can be quite complicated. And it may not work with mingw and may require a specific version of mingw or MSVC..